# print command and output of command

Tags: python

How can I print both input and output to `print`?

Examples:

```py
#pseudocode
from typing import Any
def print_verbose(input: Any) -> str:
   printf("input: {input}")
   
print_verbose(1+1):
# "1+1: 2"

x = 1
print_verbose(x)
# "x: 1"
```

I've looked into `f-strings`, `locals`, `globals`, `eval`, but probably not using the right search terms (`input`/`output` obviously points to inputs to programs).

Comment: `print_verbose` *cannot* output `1+1`, because it never sees that particular expression. You need to pass a string `"1+1"` as an argument, then parse and evaluate it as an expression to get the result.

Comment: Same with `x`: it's just a variable whose *value* is passed to the function. In both cases, you could use the `inspect` module to look at the actual source code, rather than just relying on the argument, but this isn't a good way to write code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the comments to your question and try to understand this code:

```
def print_verbose(expression):
    # The eval() function compiles and executed the code in iys argument
    print(f'{expression}: {eval(expression)}')

# Note that the expression is passed as a str
print_verbose('1+1')
# "1+1: 2"

x = 1
print_verbose('x')
# "x: 1"
```